# Is it possible to prevent overwriting files with ftp.exe?

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp

I am referring to the Windows-native ftp.exe application.  Out-of-the-box, it seems to overwrite files under any and all circumstances.

Is it possible to prevent overwriting files with ftp.exe?  If this cannot be done with specific ftp.exe arguments, can it be done using a batch process to call ftp.exe?

Comment: you did try setting the file properties with as Read-only? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are any ftp arguments nor ftp command options to do what you want explicitly.

Using a batch process looks like the way to go (if you must stick to this ftp client).

You might have to do something like:

1. Ftp connect
2. List files (remote.txt)
3. Compare remote.txt with local.txt (files you want to upload)
4. Generate uploadables.txt (containing items from local.txt not in remote.txt)
5. Ftp connect again
6. Upload uploadables.txt

Sounds fun, but I better get back to work. :-)

Comment: Here's an example of something close to my suggestion. See http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php#Batch.FtpBatchUploadOnlyNewFiles